# How can I cancel the void?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I am working unity from 3 months.so i am spawing objects and when it collide to tag full than the bool is true,when it is true it cancel spawn. cancelinvoke no working. thanks in advance

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spaw : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float startTimeBTwSpawn;

   public float timeBTwSpawn;

   public GameObject[] enemies;
   public static bool stopspawner = false;

   private void Start()
   {
       
   }
   public void Update()
   {
       Spawn();
       if (stopspawner == true)
       {
           Debug.Log("cannnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnncel");
           CancelInvoke("Spawn");
       }
   }
   void Spawn()
   {
       if (timeBTwSpawn <= 0)
       {
           int rand = Random.Range(0, enemies.Length);
           Instantiate(enemies[rand], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
           timeBTwSpawn = startTimeBTwSpawn;
       }
       else
       {
           timeBTwSpawn -= Time.deltaTime;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on your question with detail of what is not working, the error you are getting or what you are expecting that is not happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can't "cancel the void" - but you don't need to - just change your code to only run the `Spawn()` function if your `stopspawner` is `false`:

```cs
public void Update()
{ 
   if (!stopspawner) 
   {
      Spawn();
   } 
}
```

By the way, `MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke()` only cancels previous `MonoBehaviour.Invoke()` or `MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating()` calls, per [documentation](https://docs.unity.cn/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html)